# How to the get the sum of all the field with the same name in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to find the sum of all the field values of the nested array, I suck at explaining stuffs like this, I hope the code below will give you some insight of what I want to do.

The array looks like this

```
data = [
    {
        id: 8434,
        name: listName, 
        data: [
            {name: "a name",
             quantity: 20,
            }
            {name: "another name",
             quantity: 40,
            }
            {name: "another new name",
             quantity: 40,
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        id: 54343,
        name: "new list name", 
        data: [
            {name: "a name",
             quantity: 12,
            }
            {name: "another name",
             quantity: 10,
            }
            {name: "another new name",
             quantity: 16,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is how I want the data to be after carrying out the sum

```
transformed = [
{name: "a name", quantity: 32},
{name: "another name", quantity: 50},
{name: "another new name", quantity: 56}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to iterate over arrays? Do you know about [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just loop them through and create a new object..

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 8434,
        name: 'listName', 
        data: [
            {
                name: "a name",
                quantity: 20,
            },
            {
                name: "another name",
                quantity: 40,
            },
            {
                name: "another new name",
                quantity: 40,
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        id: 54343,
        name: "new list name", 
        data: [
            {
                name: "a name",
                quantity: 12,
            },
            {
                name: "another name",
                quantity: 10,
            },
            {
                name: "another new name",
                quantity: 16,
            }
        ]
    }
]


// Logic:
const transformed = []

data.forEach(d => {
    d.data.forEach(item => {
        const exist = transformed.find(t => t.name == item.name)
        if(exist) 
            exist.quantity += item.quantity
        else 
            transformed.push(item)
    })
})

console.log(transformed)
```

Output:

```js
[
  { name: 'a name', quantity: 32 },
  { name: 'another name', quantity: 50 },
  { name: 'another new name', quantity: 56 }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.flatMap()` followed by `Array.reduce()` to get the desired result.

We start by calling .flatMap() to get all the data values, then calling .reduce() on these to sum each value by `name`.

This will create an object, with a property for each name, we then call `Object.values()` to return to an array.

```js
const data = [ { id: 8434, name: 'listName', data: [ { name: "a name", quantity: 20, }, { name: "another name", quantity: 40, }, { name: "another new name", quantity: 40, } ] }, { id: 54343, name: "new list name", data: [ { name: "a name", quantity: 12, }, { name: "another name", quantity: 10, }, { name: "another new name", quantity: 16, } ] } ];

const transformed = Object.values(data.flatMap(({ data }) => data).reduce((acc, { name , quantity }) => { 
    acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, quantity: 0 };
    acc[name].quantity += quantity;
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Transformed:', transformed)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const transform = (data) => {
  const quantitySum = new Map()
  
  data.forEach(list => {
    list.data.forEach(({ name, quantity }) => {
      if (quantitySum.has(name)) {
        quantitySum.set(name, quantitySum.get(name) + quantity)
      } else {
        quantitySum.set(name, quantity)
      }
    })
  })
  
  return Array.from(quantitySum.entries())
    .map(([name, sum]) => ({
    name,
    quantity: sum
  }))
}
```